# Recover angles after transformation

Tags: python, numpy, math, trigonometry

This seems like an easy enough task but I've failed to find a solution and I've run out of ideas.

I have two angles which I employ to define some transformation coefficients. Now, I don't actually have the values for those angles in my real data, I have the coefficients and I need to *recover* the angles.

I thought the [`arctan2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) function would take care of this, but there are cases where it fails to recover the proper `a1` angle and instead returns its `180` complement, which later affects the recovery of the `a2` angle.

What am I doing wrong and how can I recover the `a1, a2` angles properly?

```
import numpy as np

# Repeat 100 times
for _ in range(100):
    # Define two random angles in the range [-pi, pi]. I do not have these
    # angles in my actual data, I have the A,B,C coefficients shown below.
    a1, a2 = np.random.uniform(-180., 180., (2,))

    # Transformation coefficients using the above angles.
    # This is the data I actually have.
    a1_rad, a2_rad = np.deg2rad(a1), np.deg2rad(a2)  # to radians
    A = - np.sin(a1_rad) * np.sin(a2_rad)
    B = np.cos(a1_rad) * np.sin(a2_rad)
    C = np.cos(a2_rad)

    # Recover a1 using 'arctan2' (returns angle in the range [-pi, pi])
    a1_recover = np.arctan2(-A / B, 1.)

    # Now obtain sin(a2), used below to obtain 'a2'
    sin_a2 = -A / np.sin(a1_recover)

    # Recover a2 using 'arctan2', where: C = cos(a2)
    a2_recover = np.arctan2(sin_a2, C)

    # Print differences.
    a1_recover = np.rad2deg(a1_recover)
    print("a1: {:.2f} = {} - {}".format(a1 - a1_recover, a1, a1_recover))
    a2_recover = np.rad2deg(a2_recover)
    print("a2: {:.2f} = {} - {}\n".format(a2 - a2_recover, a2, a2_recover))
```

Comment: So you want to find `a1` and `a2` given `A`,`B`,`C`?

Comment: Exactly, I want to recover the *exact* values defined in `a1, a2 = np.random.uniform(-180., 180., (2,))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `a2_rad` equals 0, `(A, B, C)` equals `(0, 0, 1)` no matter what `a1_rad` equals. So the transformation is not 1-to-1. Therefore there is no well-defined inverse.

```
def ABC(a1, a2):
    a1_rad, a2_rad = np.deg2rad(a1), np.deg2rad(a2)  # to radians
    A = - np.sin(a1_rad) * np.sin(a2_rad)
    B = np.cos(a1_rad) * np.sin(a2_rad)
    C = np.cos(a2_rad)
    return A, B, C

print(ABC(0, 0))
# (-0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
print(90, 0)
# (-0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
print(-90, 0)
# (-0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

A similar problem happens at the opposite (South) pole. Within the limits of floating point accuracy, all these values (of the form `ABC(a1, 180)`) are essentially equal too:

```
ABC(1, 180)
# (-2.1373033680837913e-18, 1.2244602795081332e-16, -1.0)

ABC(0, 180)
# (-0.0, 1.2246467991473532e-16, -1.0)

ABC(90, 180)
# (-1.2246467991473532e-16, 7.498798913309288e-33, -1.0)
```

---

You can think of `a1`, `a2` as coordinates on a unit sphere where `a1`
represents the angle away from the x-axis (more often called `theta`) and `a2`
represents the angle away from the z-axis (often called `phi`).

`A`,`B`,`C` represents the same point on the unit sphere in Cartesian coordinates.

Usually [spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) restrict `a1` to the range `[0, 2*pi)` and `a2` to the range `[0, pi]`.
Even with this restriction, the North and South poles have more than one (actually infinite number of) valid representation.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it had to be an issue of a degenerate solution that could not be uniquely solved, your answer explains it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restore angle sign information because it was loosed in `A,B` calculation (formation).

8 possible combinations of `sin/cos` signs give only 4 results of `A/B` signs (and sign of `cos(a2)` cannot help here).

Note that for spherical coordinates inclination range is only `0..Pi`

Answer (score 0):

You should use np.arctan2(-A , B) instead of np.arctan2(-A / B, 1.). With the latter you are losing information: A = -1 and B = 1 will give the same result as A - 1 and B = -1, hence the 180 mismatch sometimes.
If you restrict a2 to be in (0,180) then you can recover the angles. Note that with this restriction a2 can be recovered as acos(C). (I've tried this but since my program is in C it might not be helpful)